# How to view or edit Google Sheets offline?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-sheets-offline

I have followed the instructions to setup Offline mode access to Google Drive and it worked well. Surprisingly Google Sheets do not open on offline mode, giving an "internal error", however can open word documents and edit them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

### Use Google Drive files offline

This answer requires Google Chrome web browser to be installed and regularly updated.

> If you aren't connected to a Wi-Fi or mobile network, you can still
>   view and edit files, including:
>
> - Google Docs
> - Google Sheets
> - Google Slides
>
> #### Open files offline
>
> To turn on offline access:
>
> - You must be connected to the Internet.
> - Use  the Google Chrome browser.
> - Don't use incognito mode.
> - Install and enable [Google Docs offline Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs-offline/ghbmnnjooekpmoecnnnilnnbdlolhkhi). The Google Docs extension makes it possible to edit your documents, spreadsheets and presentations when you aren’t connected to the internet. Plus, you can copy and paste between Docs, Sheets and Slides.
> - Make sure you have enough free space on your device to save your files.
>
> #### Open your Google Drive files offline
>
> - Open Chrome. Make sure you're [signed in to Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/185277).
> - Go to [drive.google.com/drive/settings](https://drive.google.com/drive/settings).
> - Check the box in the **Offline** category next to "Sync Google Docs, Sheets, Slides & Drawings files to this computer so that you can edit offline."
>
>   [image]

<sub>**Source:** [Use Google Drive files offline – Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)</sub>